# explorer.exe eating memory like crazy

Tags: windows-7, memory, windows-explorer

I have a Windows 7 operating system. When I boot up and do nothing, explorer.exe starts to consume memory like crazy, like around 2GBs and so. When I kill it from task manager, everything is still fine and it will not do the same thing again.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Does this happen if you boot to `Safe Mode`?  Explorer.exe is Windows Explorer.  I assume when you kill the process you eventually start the process again.

Comment: Use MSConfig to disable 3rd party start-ups and services. Reboot. Does it still do it?

Comment: follow this http://pastebin.com/peqLGxSa and give me the trace.

Comment: @magicandre1981 I hope I did it right: http://1drv.ms/1G05wHL

Comment: the kernel.etl is useless. I need the **HighMemoryUsage.etl**. I've updated the command to store the file under C:\temp. Adjust this parameter to a valid folder on your drive.

Comment: @magicandre1981 I did what you said and file is at : http://www.filedropper.com/highmemoryusageetl

Comment: ok, I posted an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an addon in Explorer installed which generates dynamically code (shown as `?!?` in WPA) and calls HTML functions to load flash (`Flash64_15_0_0_189.ocx`):

[image]

[image]

And Flash causes the Memory Allocation (`KernelBase.dll!VirtualAlloc`).

Scan your PC for malware and disable all 3rd party Addons with [ShellExView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html)

Comment: Thanks, I uninstalled flash completely, I do not use it anyway.. Now svchost is growing but I think it is ok?

Comment: how large does it grow? 200-300MB is ok, when the svchost.exe host Superfetch or WindowsUpdate. Both can consume a bit more RAM compared to others.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and efforts. Yes around 300MB.. Thanks a lot.

Comment: you should still do a virus scan.